# Movie app using fetch API

Tags: javascript, api, classes

The code will create a new **Movie** class and then with the response of the API call, will render html using the data.

Although the code works, I imagine it will get quite convoluted, now that everything after the new class is created, has to be nested into the event listener. There must be a more correct way to do this. For example, would it be possible to get the response to a new Class object without creating a new class instance inside of the API call?

```js
/*separate function for api call. It gets the movie data*/
function getMovie(movieTitle) {
  return fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${movieTitle}&apikey=3861f60e`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
}


/*Movie Class*/
class Movie {
constructor(data){
  Object.assign(this, data);
  }
  
  renderMovie() {
    return ` 
    <div class="movie-container">
    <div class="image-container">
           <img src='${this.Poster}'/>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-content-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h4>${this.Title}</h4>
        <p>${this.imdbRating}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-details">
        <p>${this.Runtime}</p>
        <p>${this.Genre}</p>
        <button class="add-watchlist-btn">Watchlist</button>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-desc">
        <p>${this.Plot}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  `;
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const searchPage = document.querySelector(".search-page-container");
const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search-btn");
const searchInput = document.querySelector(".input-search-bar");


/* If I create the instance inside of here, then anything that I need to do further, has to be nested inside. This doesn't feel right at all*/
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  getMovie(searchInput.value).then((res) => {
    container.removeChild(searchPage);
    container.innerHTML += new Movie(res).renderMovie();
    let btn = document.querySelector(".add-watchlist-btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("button clicked");
    });
  });
  searchInput.value = "";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Movie App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/facd5daff4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <div class="header-group">
              <h1>Find Your Film</h1>
              <h4><a>My Watchlist</a></h4>
          </div>
                </header>
                <form>
        <div class="search-bar">
          <label for="search">
            <input
              id="search"
              class="input-search-bar"
              type="text"
              name="search"
              placeholder="Search for a movie"
            />
          </label>
            <button class="search-btn">Search</button>
                    </form>
         </div>
         <div class="search-page-container">
           
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems:

- you create a class instance with `object.assign` from a JSON call, which is quite risky. You don't always know what properties the json will return.
- your class returns html, but then later you add a click function to that html outside of the class, which looks very un-OOP to me. A class should be responsible for all its own content.
- It seems you need the `class` only to generate HTML. In that case it might work better as a function.
- you create HTML as text strings which is very error prone.

I would try to organise the code something like this.

```
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let res = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${searchInput.value}&apikey=3861f60e`)
  let json = await res.json()
  // TODO CHECK HERE IF JSON ACTUALLY HAS MOVIE DATA
  container.removeChild(searchPage)
  searchInput.value = ""
  let div = renderMovie(json)
  container.appendChild(div)
});

// Just an example
function renderMovie(json) {
   let moviediv = document.createElement("div")
   moviediv.classList.add("movie-container")
   let title = document.createElement("h4")
   title.innerText = json.title
   let button = document.createElement("button")
   button.innerText = "add to watchlist"
   button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("added to watchlist")
   })
   moviediv.appendChild(title)
   moviediv.appendChild(button)
   return moviediv
}
```